# jQuery find() not playing nicely with Chrome. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

My website uses AJAX to pull some data from another page and display it locally. The external page is retrieved using `jQuery.get()`, and then I pull the data I need using `jQuery.find()`. This works perfectly fine in IE, FF, Opera and Safari, but fails in Chrome. After tracing the data, I can see that the external page data is being returned, it is the find() function that is failing. It looks like this:

```
var f = $(data).find('h5 > a');
```

I did some searches and haven't seen very much concerning this. Someone mentioned that it might be a dataType issue, so changed the `get()` to an `ajax()` statement and changed the dataType to 'text', but it is still failing in Chrome (still works in everything else).

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the value of `data`?  It seems odd that `find` would function differently in chrome.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Are you trying to bypass any X-domain restrictions? At a stretch, you may find you have invalid HTML and Chrome is rendering it differently to other browsers (such that `h5 > a` is false).

Comment: Code takes the place of a thousand words.

Comment: A jsfiddle example would be nice! What is the result in chrome, instead of the expected?

Comment: I had an odd one yesterday like this.  I was using get and find to get the links out of a page and it wouldnt find the links in the body tag, I had to put the links in a div in the body for it to find them....odd

Comment: The value of 'data' in this case is the entire web page, from <html> to </html>. I can't provide specifics because this is an as-of-yet unreleased product website for a large retail food chain, and everything at this point is confidential.

Comment: Darn enter key submitted. Ok, so the jQuery version is 1.6.1. The site is hosted on a third party Ecommerce website, so much of my access to the master page is limited or non-existent. So I can't, for example, change the version of jQuery I am using.    I'll check fiddler for clues. Makes no sense to me either why one browser would fail, but that is what is happening. It could be that Chrome uses JavaScript acceleration techniques and it is breaking something.

Comment: @ToddDavis - Try to reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net. You wouldn't need to include any code or details that you are prohibited from sharing, just create a minimal test case.

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange glitch in jQuery

If you write

```
var htmlContent = '<html><body><div class="toto">Hello World!</div></body></html>';
$(htmlContent).find('.toto'); // length = 0
$('<div>' + htmlContent + '</div>').find('.toto'); // length = 1
```

The only workaround I know is to place your html markup in a div tag.

```
$('<div>' + myHtml + '</div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try var f = $(data).find('> h5 > a');

p.s. It would be handy if you could post the value of data as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, and I now have it fixed. For what is it worth, it is still a Chrome weirdism. And for the people that said, "Can we see the data", I'm sorry I could not provide it, but it would have helped a lot if I could. Anyway, the solution had nothing to do with the find() routine, but did have something to do with selectors.

Long story short, there is a breadcrumb control on the page. The breadcrumb is key to what is going on, because it has links to the pages that led to the current page, and it is one of those links that we need to get to. So a typical breadcrumb looks like this:

Home > Category > Product

I need to pull data from the category page. In IE, FF, and everything else, this code does that:

**var categoryName = $('#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(3) > a').html();**

In Chrome, this selector grabs the wrong child. However, in Chrome, this works:

**var categoryName = $('#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(2) > a').html();**

(we are grabbing the 2nd child, not the 3rd)

Not sure why Chrome counts children differently? It seems that Chrome seems to be counting from 0, while other browsers count from 1? Just a guess on my part. Anyway, Chrome was grabbing the wrong URL and thus the page that was being returned wasn't the one I was looking for. This was fixed by detecting the presence of Chrome and compensating for it.